# Excel VBA Syntax Error

Tags: excel, vba

I've made what i thought is a simple script in VBA that performs the specified formula and applies it all the way down column D.
When i run it i get a Runtime Error 13 Type mismatch.
Ive narrowed it down the actual formula part by replacing the formula with something simple like 1+1 and then it works fine. Any advise?

**Type Mismatch error on:**

```
Sub FillFormula()
Range("D2").Formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(D2;" - ";"")"
Range("D2", "D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
End Sub
```

**Works fine with:**

```
Sub FillFormula()
Range("D2").Formula = "=1+1"
Range("D2", "D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Use commas rather than semi-colons in VBA.

Comment: Quotes in quotes must be double quotes to quote them as quotes: `"=SUBSTITUTE(D2, "" - "", """")"`

Comment: @SJR Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe there are some European versions of Excel that use `;` instead of `,`

Comment: @Maldred - in spreadsheets, but I think VBA always uses commas (though could be wrong), although an alternative is to use `FormulaLocal`.

Comment: @AlexK.  Well said. :)

Answer (score 1):

- Write the Excel formula on `D2` the way you want it to be and make sure it works in Excel.
- Select D2 and run the following:

---

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

Use whatever is shown in the immediate window. It should work. [I have been using it quite a lot.](https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/Formula.vb)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
Used advice from everyone and in no time had it working.
Final Formula:

```
Sub FillFormula()
Range("F2").Formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(D2,""-"","""")"
Range("F2", "F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
End Sub
```